# How do you locate django template errors?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a template which does not parse - instead django raises:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '"{%' from '"{%'
```

Unfortunately, Django does not disclose where the error is. Is there a tool that can disclose the location of syntax errors in Django templates?

Answer (score 2):

Interactive debugger in django-extensions [`runserver_plus`](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runserver_plus.html) command will make it easier to introspect template node content and template source, as well as look into context variables.

Other than that, be sure that templatetag is importable and do not raise an errors.

Unfortunately, I do not any easier way than that.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but it doesn't really yield any more information than exists in the error message.

Comment: Are you able to start interactive debugger on each of the trackstace lines? (there is an icon on the right side)

Comment: Yes, as I say, it doesn't really show anything concrete until the frame containing the whole text.

Answer (score 2):

Good question，you could check error traceback again:

- The highlighted template line is the start of the node inside which the broken code resides. I call the node the *parent node*
- The last but two item in the tracestack is the key to find the error. Check variables inside its *Local vars*

  - 'nodelist' -- the list of nodes before the error, inside the parent node.
  - 'compiled_result' -- if there is one, is the last complete node (not including TextNode) before the error

For example, template which looks like

```
{% block foo %}{{ "{% }}
```

raises a error tracestack, the 'nodelist' inside the last but two item could be

```
nodelist      []
```

Which means the error is around the first child-node of the block foo.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it tells you the exact location but Django Debug Toolbar should help here to some extent.

https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar

a tour http://vimeo.com/6640136